# Facebook Graph API - authorization types?

Tags: facebook

I'm struggling with the new Facebook Graph API, perhaps someone here can help.

Here is what I want to do: provide a ‘login w/ FB’ button, throw to /authorize, get a code, throw to /access_token, get an access_token, and be able to hit https://graph.facebook.com/me for info about the user.

When I try to use type=client_cred in the /authorize call, I get an access_token that lets me hit URLs with userIDs or names, but not /me. I receive an error stating I need a valid token.

If I can't hit /me, how do I figure out who the current user is?

What exactly should I use in the type param if I want a website to access a users data? I've seen posts with type=web_server, etc, but I can't seem to find a sure fire way to do, what I think, is pretty simple...

Thanks ahead of time for any help thats provided...

Comment: No, I'm just doing raw REST calls right now - eventually I want to move to the SDK, but I can't even seem to get this simple step working heh...

Answer (score 5):

> When I try to use type=client_cred in the /authorize call, I get an access_token that lets me hit URLs with userIDs or names, but not /me. I receive an error stating I need a valid token.

`client_cred` is intended for your app to validate that it is, indeed, the app. It's used for things like subscribing to Facebook's real-time update API. It imparts **no** user authentication.

You need to follow Facebook's [OAuth instructions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/). It does not use the `type` parameter in any way. You'll be:

- Sending the user to https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize with a callback URL set.
- If the user says OK, they'll be redirected to your callback URL with a verification string as a URL parameter.
- You take that verification string and request an access token from https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token

That access token lets you function as the user and access the `me` URLs.

Comment: I have followed FBs instructions, but can't get an access_token. When I do exactly as stated by you and FB I get this error when hitting /authorize: {
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "Error validating verification code."
   }
}

Comment: Make sure your Connect URL in your application settings at http://facebook.com/developers has the same domain name as your callback URI. If they don't match, Facebook will reject your requests.

Comment: +1 for ceejayoz for stressing on using the same callback url...it can be a nightmare guessing how a verification code can go wrong....

Comment: Having the same problems.  I can only get things to work using type=client_cred.  However, the Facebook account I've connected with shows that I do have an active session.  There is no "connect URL" in the settings, however the "site domain" field does match.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: nevermind.  figured out my problem.  make 100% sure that redirect_uri is identical when making authroize and access_token call!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I solved it.

First: **Dont use &type=client_cred**.

Second: Use the same URL everywhere!!!

*My example:*

My firs link:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=_MY_APP_ID_&state=_RANDOM_NUMBER_&redirect_uri=http://mysite.ru/ru/site_users.html?op=fbreg">FB login</a>
```

When I got the code:

```
$nexturl  = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".$AppId."&redirect_uri=http://mysite.ru/ru/site_users.html?op=fbreg&client_secret=".$AppSec."&code=".$fbCode;
$response = @file_get_contents($nexturl);   
$params   = null;
parse_str($response, $params);
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=".$params['access_token'];
$arrResponse = json_decode(@file_get_contents($graph_url));
```

In $arrResponse i got all info about current user.

The value of URL should be **the same everywhere**. In the code and in https://developers.facebook.com/apps/.

In my case it is this: `http://mysite.ru/ru/site_users.html?op=fbreg`

The following are all incorrect using my example.

- `http://mysite.ru/`
- `http://mysite/`
- `http://mysite/ru/site_users.html`

Thats all. Very stupid problem. I solved it for three days :(

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be something like that:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=...&redirect_uri=...&scope=user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream&display=page

The scope should specify permissions you need as listed here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

Display values can be found here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: That got me further than the FB instructions, but I'm still hitting a wall. Now I get an error when I hit the /authorize call: {
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "Error validating verification code."
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

do you solve it?i have the same error like yours
i find a page that explain this problem
http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/

if use type=client_cred, you need to change "me" to a user id, and the userid can find in the "code" param, just see the airtle:)

Answer (score 0):

This answer should clarify nategood's last comment

> nevermind. figured out my problem. make 100% sure that redirect_uri is identical when making authroize and access_token call! – nategood Mar 24 at 0:54

I struggled with this issue for a long time. Facebooks documentation is poor, and answers on these sites seem to fall in to one of two categories: use type=client_cred or don't use 
type.

Don't use "type=client_cred".
Follow the [facebook documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and just make sure that the redirect_uri you use in your code request to:
*http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?*

is the same as the redirect_uri you use in your access_token request to:
*https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?*