# "privacy value" on post on Wall per php and curl not work

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl

I want to receive Curl and PHP on my post wall.
I also get everything out, I'm the only one who can read it.
Stands in the documentaries that I set the parameter "privacy" to {"value": "EVERYONE"} must be set so that the entry can be read by all.
However, this does not work. I'm still the only one.
How can I change that?

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";   
$client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$postString = "client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret&type=client_cred";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
$token = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$message = rawurlencode("Ich liebe hannaee");
$url = "https://api.facebook.com/method/stream.publish";
$apost = array("message"=>$message,"uid"=>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,"access_token"=>$token,"privacy"=>json_encode(array("value"=>"EVERYONE")));
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $apost);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/, you need publish_stream permission (see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and your application must not be in sandbox mode.

**Update** : Answer to [Facebook Graph API - authorization types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838396/facebook-graph-api-authorization-types) explains that why **type=client_cred** shouldn't be used.

Comment: I have the permit, otherwise nothing would show up on my message board, right?
Similarly, it would not run in the sandbox, I use the Secret Key and APIID my application and my goal as AccountId